# How can I fit the parametres of t-distribution if I know the number of degrees of freedom in R?

Tags: r

I have some data. Does anybody know a function which can fit the parameters of a t-distribution of this data when I know the numbers of degrees of freedom?

Thanks!

Comment: You might also want to mention which parameters you're interested in.  Are we talking about some sort of shifted t-distribution?  Do you want to estimate a non-centrality parameter?  What are you trying to estimate?

Comment: See the `fitdistr` function in the `MASS` package -- especially the second example in `?fitdistr` ...

Comment: I want to estimate mean = mu and variance = sigma like the function fit.st of the QRM-packages does it, but this function also estimate the number of degrees of freedom but I just know this number.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding @Ben Bolker's comment:

You may use the `fitdistr` function in *R* `MASS` package.

See the second example in `?fitdistr` function help. Also in this [pdf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MASS/MASS.pdf), page 50.

```
library(MASS)

#generate a random sample with t distribution, where the degrees of freedom = 9.
set.seed(123)
x2 <- rt(250, df = 9)

#find the parameters for the t distribution
fitdistr(x2, "t", df = 9)
```

the output is:

```
       m             s     
  -0.01069496    1.04410551 
 ( 0.07222623) ( 0.05434369)
```

where the second line represents the parameter estimates, and the numbers inside brackets are their standard deviations.

`fitdistr` uses the Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE) method to adjust the parameters of a given distribution.
For a theoretical insight about MLE, you might find @Glen_b's [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49544/how-much-calculus-is-necessary-to-understand-maximum-likelihood-estimation) helpful.

Reference.

Venables, W. N., & Ripley, B. D. (2002). Modern Applied Statistics with S (4a ed., p. 495).