# What is the correct definition of the Likelihood function?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, conditional-probability, likelihood, generative-models

I am doing the CS229:Machine Learning of Stanford Engineering Everywhere. All trhough the first chapter he uses

$$L(\theta) = P(Y | X; \theta)$$

i.e. the likelihood of the parameter $\theta$ is given by the cond. prob. of Y given X

Now in the second chapter, when talking about Gaussian Discriminant Analysis, shuddenly without any explaination our likelihood looks like this:

$$L(\theta) = P(Y \cap X; \theta)$$

What happened here? Which likelihood function is used when? I find the first likelihood a much more natural choice.

I am talking about [page 10 of this script](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/cs229-notes2.pdf)

Comment: **Conventions:** The notation $Y\cup X$ is quite unusual since $X$ and $Y$ are random variables. A more natural notation would be $P(Y,X|\theta)$. Note also that capital letters are usually reserved for random variables, which realisations are denoted with lower case letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with [general definitions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112451/maximum-likelihood-estimation-mle-in-layman-terms) of likelihood. With likelihood you are not really interested in probabilities, but in likelihood of $\theta$ given your data. It is calculated using probability of data using some model with parameters $\theta$, i.e.

$$L(\theta|X) = \prod_i f_\theta(x_i)$$

Now, in your examples two different likelihoods are described. In the first case, you have a regression model of $Y$ conditional on $X$ and in the second case, you have a *joint likelihood* of $X$ and $Y$ in bivariate model. This is the same as you can have conditional probabilities and joint probabilities, they are both probabilities, so have the same properties, but describe different cases.

Answer (score 5):

The two likelihoods are related by the following equation:
$$P(Y \cap X\,|\,\Theta) = P(Y\,|\,X,\Theta)P(X\,|\,\Theta)$$
So, the joint probability of $Y$ and $X$ has to account for two things:

1. The probability of generating $Y$ given $X$ and $\Theta$
2. The probability of generating $X$ given $\Theta$

$P(Y\,|\,X,\Theta)$ only accounts for (1), and would be preferred when you only care about predicting Y when X is known. The joint likelihood looks at the probability of generating both X and Y given model parameter $\Theta$. This could be valuable if you want your model to predict X as well as Y given X. Put another way, $P(X\,|\,\Theta)$ is a way of measuring to what extent your model knows what kinds of $X$ are likely to occur in your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

It just seems that in the second case, $X$ and $Y$ are both modelled jointly in a *generative* model and you can write the joint likelihood as $P(X, Y | \theta)$

For example, now if you assume X and Y are independent, the joint log likelihood can be written as:

$$
\log L(\theta) = \log P(X |\theta) + \log P(Y|\theta)
$$