# What is maximum likelihood estimation in logistic regression?

Tags: r, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic

Can you please explain in simple way.

Is it so important in logistic regression?

Comment: That is a very basic question. I suggest you do a search on it before posting (or migrating) this question to CrossValidated.

Comment: see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112451/maximum-likelihood-estimation-mle-in-layman-terms/171468#171468