# Difference between variance and standard deviation: Is this popular answer wrong?

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, linear

In this popular question, [Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE) in layman terms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112451/maximum-likelihood-estimation-mle-in-layman-terms), The most voted answer by @gregmacfarlane says

> In a linear model, we assume that the points follow a normal (Gaussian) probability distribution, with mean $x\beta$ and standard deviation $\sigma^2$

Is this statement wrong? where it should be with "variance" $\sigma^2$ but not "standard deviation". And why in the end of the answer, `r`, `summary` on linear model says "Residual standard error: 1.32", but not "Residual variance: 1.32"?

Comment: Yeah, that's an obvious typo/mistake. I just fixed it.

Comment: @MatthewGunn i think it is still not fixed. since the code has sigma2 every where, I think it should be sigma. because `rnorm` function takes sd as input parameter not variance

Comment: Good eye. I'm not fluent in R, but I think you're right.

Comment: Perhaps a good question for meta. What's the right course of action when an old but popular answer on a popular question has a small error in the code and what appears to be a figure generated from that code?

Comment: @MatthewGunn I am sure the answer is wrong...  In the results of `linear.MLE$estimate` the answer is $2.7$ and $1.71$, where, $1.7$ is the square of $1.3$!!!

Comment: As I commented below, that answer is not "wrong". As @MatthewGunn wrote, it "has a small error" - this is a much more fair description.

Comment: The best possible errors to make are the obvious and inconsequential ones that any engaged reader will know how to fix.  Textbooks are chock full of these--especially at advanced levels.  People usually appreciate having them pointed out so they can be corrected, but making a big deal of it is rarely productive.  Writing "$\sigma^2$" instead of "$\sigma$" in a few places is about as minor as it gets--certainly not worthy of three exclamation points.

Comment: @whuber thanks for your comments. The reason I was excited of it is because I spent a lot of time to investigate the relationship between manually optimize the function and use R. I was confused for a long time and thinking about it may be non convergence or numerical issue. Finally I found the answer was not correct...

Comment: OP of the problem question here. I [have made the corrections as suggested](https://stats.stackexchange.com/revisions/112469/6), and I'm glad the @hxd1011 took the time to uncover my errors. There were a half-dozen chunks that needed correction, and I additionally added a constrained optimization to keep the variance positive.