# Confusion about interpreting log likelihood (and likelihood ratio test) output

Tags: maximum-likelihood, lme4-nlme

I am using the `nlme` package in R to use mixed effects models to analyze multilevel (i.e., students nested within classrooms) data.

I am confused about interpreting the log likelihood output from these functions, and while there are [other questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112451/maximum-likelihood-estimation-mle-in-layman-terms) that address *why* the log is taken of the likelihood statistic and why it is negative, it is not clear how these apply to interpreting these values.

In particular, a negative log likelihood is output. Since estimation methods maximize the log likelihood, I understand a larger value indicates better fit.

**Does this interpretation apply to the (negative) log likelihood output**, so that a larger (i.e., closer to `0`) value indicates better fit, so that if I were comparing, for example, log likelihood values of `-3146.9` and `-2931.41` using the `anova()` function, and a likelihood ratio test indicated a test statistic associated with a p-value less than `.05`, then the model with the log likelihood of `-2931.41` demonstrates better fit?

Comment: No. we minimise the negative log likelihood.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We take the log-likelihood because each case in the dataset gets a likelihood, and the log-likelihood is the product of these likelihoods. But each of these likelihoods is less than 1, and when you multiply lots of numbers less than 1 together you tend to get really, really small numbers.

Nothing wrong with those really small numbers - *except* that we hit precision limits on the computers that we use. Try exponentiating your log-likelihoods of -3000 and -2000. I suspect that your computer will say that they are both zero - so the likelihood of both models is zero - and they are indistinguishable.

So instead of trying to multiply lots of values togehter, it is easier to take their logs, and add them together. So we don't get a likelihood, we get a log-likelihood, and we don't hit precision limits.

Then @PlayStarCraftOkLetsGo's answer.

Answer (score 4):

We try to minimise the negative log-likelihood function, which is equivalent to maximising the log-likelihood function. The model with the lower negative log-likelihood value would be a better fit.

Comment: By smaller, we mean smaller in absolute value, not smaller as in more negative, correct?

Comment: I think it should be smaller, as in more negative, the better model.

Comment: Lower, rather than smaller.