# How to draw the Likehood Function against the parameter?

Tags: self-study, likelihood

Let $(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ be a random sample from a uniform distribution on the interval $(-\theta,\theta)$, where $\theta$ is an unknown positive number.

A particular sample of size $5$ gives values $0.87,-0.43,0.12,-0.92$ and $0.58$.

How can I draw a graph of the likelihood function $L(\theta)$ against $\theta$ for this sample?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recall that the likelihood function is

$$
L(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n f_\theta(X_i)
$$

where $f_\theta$ is a probability density function (or probability mass function) parametrized by $\theta$. So your homework excercise asks you to evaluate the likelihood function with using different values of $\theta$ and plot $\theta$ vs $L(\theta)$. Check [Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE) in layman terms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112451/maximum-likelihood-estimation-mle-in-layman-terms) to learn more on maximum likelihood.

Comment: I manage to get $L( \theta )=c(\frac{1}{\theta})^n$ for $-\theta<x_i<\theta$, how should proceed to draw the graph?

Comment: @Mathxx you need to choose some range for possible values of $\theta$, an then plot those values on x-axis and the likelihood function evaluated on those values on y-axis.

Comment: Can you show me how to as I don't really understand the solution given by? Thanks in advance.