# Simple explanation of maximum likelihood estimation

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, maximum-likelihood, intuition

I was watching a video from code emporium, here [he describes Maximum Likelihood Estimation](https://youtu.be/-p1ldISb90Q?t=164) (MLE) as to finding weights which maximizes the probability of seeing the training data (D = [X,Y])

> $\theta^{MLE} =argmax \{ P(Y|X;\theta) \}$

Let's consider our training data is XOR data

```
Input   Output
A   B
0   0   0
0   1   1
1   0   1
1   1   0
```

and say this data's real probability distribuiton is the blue one $P(Y|X)$ and our current model's (randomly initialized weights) probability disbribution is the red one $P(Y|X;\theta_{Random})$

[image]

Then the aim of Maximum Likelihood Estimation is to push the weights from randomly initialitzed weights to the real weights which approximately "describes" our real data distribution.

> MLE = $ \{ P(Y|X;\theta_{Random})\rightarrow P(Y|X;\theta_{Real})\approx P(Y|X)\}$

**Question 1:** Is my thinking right; Is this the correct approach to describe MLE?

In gradient descent, to train a model we have to minimize a cost function but in MLE we are maximizing it. To solve this [in here he talks about Negative Log Likelihood](https://youtu.be/-p1ldISb90Q?t=505) which is a negative added to the log converted MLE?

**Question 2**: How is adding a negative to log converted MLE maximises MLE?

My intiution tells me instead of learning the real distribution $P(Y|X;\theta_{Real})$ this should have pushed away the weights to some random distribution?

Comment: See also [Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE) in layman terms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112451/maximum-likelihood-estimation-mle-in-layman-terms/112480#112480)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maximum likelihood is a method for estimating parameters by maximizing the probability of the observed data. The main ingredients are:

- The data: $D=(X,Y)$
- The model parameters: $\theta$
- The model that relates data to the parameters: $P(D|\theta)$ (which can be written differently, depending on the situation: $P(Y|X, \theta)$ is one of the possibilities.)

One would typically name the probability of observing data given parameters *likelihood* and write it as $L(\theta|D)=P(D|\theta)$. This is just a change of notation. One then maximizes the likelihood in respect to the values of the parameters:
\begin{equation}
\hat{\theta}=\mathrm{argmax}_\theta L(\theta|D).
\end{equation}

Quite often the likelihood is a product of many identical functions for different data points. In this case it is mathematically more convenient to maximize its logarithm, i.e. the *log-likelihood*: $LL(\theta|D) = \log L(\theta|D)$. The likelihood and its logarithm has the same maximum, since logarithm is a monotonous function. Finally, maximizing a function is the same as minimizing its negative, therefore minimizing a *negative log-likelihood* is the same as maximizing the *log-likelihood*, which is the same as maximizing the likelihood. This is important since the optimization algorithms are often spelled explicitly only for minimization (or only for maximization).