# Maximum Likelihood estimator and one application for real life

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood

I am studying maximum likelihood estimators (MLE) right now. I am trying to do a little article about how to apply maximum likelihood estimators to one real life problem.

But I see that MLE mostly is about to "prove" estimators to known distributions.

In some universities exams I see that professors give you a probability density function that is very... mmm..."exotic", and you figure out its parameters by MLE, but I'm not sure that those PDFs work in real life.

Am I wrong in my apprehension?

Are there some real applications of MLE in real life for me to write my article about?

Comment: MLE is a big deal for fitting parameters to data, but you always have to choose _some_ form for your model. Maybe it's what your professor gives you. Maybe it's a neural network with (not kidding) billions of parameters, for something like translating text. The general principle of MLE is the same for both.

Comment: As Arya said, MLEs are heavily used in many applications that involve statistics, including, notably, machine learning. If you're looking for a good textbook specifically on likelihoods and MLEs, I suggest *In All Likelihood: Statistical Modelling and Inference Using Likelihood* by Yudi Pawitan.

Comment: thank you Arya. I didn't know it was applied in neuronal netwoek as well.. thank you @The pointer , I really wanted a book like that. Thank you.

Comment: and , for example I have a histogram. .how can I make my own PDF from it ? are there some tecnic ?

Comment: You could find some help here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112451/maximum-likelihood-estimation-mle-in-layman-terms/112480#112480