# What is the data $p_{data}$ and probability of the model $p_{model}(\textbf{x}, \boldsymbol{\theta})$ in the deep learning book?

Tags: neural-networks, maximum-likelihood

[image]

In the Maximum Likelihood section of the Deep Learning Book ([Section 5.5](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html)), the dataset (examples) is denoted by $\mathbb{X} = \{\boldsymbol{x}^{(1)}, \cdots, \boldsymbol{x}^{(m)}\}$. Note here the bold letters. Then the data-generating distribution has a $\textbf{x}$ (note that the calligraphy is different) as argument $p_{data}(\textbf{x})$. Later on, we see again the data-generating distribution with another calligraphic different argument: $p_{data}(\boldsymbol{x})$. According to the notation [used by the authors](https://github.com/goodfeli/dlbook_notation/blob/master/notation_example.pdf) the notation $\boldsymbol{x}$ is the most understandable (every example is a vector, or a random variable).

**Question #1**: Does $p_{data}(\textbf{x})$ and $p_{data}(\boldsymbol{x})$ are the same?

**Question #2**: Why the parametric family of probability distributions is called $p_{model}$? In other words, which *model* this function refers to? Maybe the *parametric model* that [Elements of Stats.](https://hastie.su.domains/Papers/ESLII.pdf), page 265 refers to?

Interestingly, in [Bertsekas and Tsitsiklis, 2002,](http://www.athenasc.com/probbook.html) this function $p_{model}$ is considered as joint PDF $p_X(x; \theta)$, which is, effectively, **the Likelihood function**.

Then we have the same situation with $p_{model}(\textbf{x}; \boldsymbol{\theta})$ and $p_{model}(\boldsymbol{x}; \boldsymbol{\theta})$. Note again the difference in calligraphy.

**Question #3**: Does $p_{model}(\textbf{x}; \boldsymbol{\theta})$ and $p_{model}(\boldsymbol{x}; \boldsymbol{\theta})$ are the same?